# Testing PayPal Donations with a Sandbox Account

Tags: wordpress, button, paypal

I have a WordPress form that processes data and redirects to this url to complete the PayPal donation

`https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=sb-5mepe4127835%40business.example.com&currency_code=USD&amount= <amount>&return=http://example.local/about`

However, when I submit the form I receive this error from PayPal

> We can't complete your donation. This organization's account is inactive.

What am I missing? The reason I have it setup this way is because I want WordPress to save the form data and send a thank you/confirmation email after the payment is complete.

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=sb-5mepe4127835%40business.example.com&currency_code=USD&amount=&return=http://example.local/about

When testing with any sandbox account, change the domain to point to the `www.sandbox.paypal.com` sandbox environment , i.e.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donations&business=sb-5mepe4127835%40business.example.com&currency_code=USD&amount=&return=http://example.local/about